# postfix problem sending email "RCPT reject localhost not listed"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

i am hacing a hard time getting postfix to send emails.

this is the mail.log entry:

```
Jun 30 18:27:46 vm21 postfix/smtpd[15682]: warning: ::1: address not listed for hostname localhost
Jun 30 18:27:46 vm21 postfix/smtpd[15682]: connect from unknown[::1]
Jun 30 18:27:46 vm21 postfix/smtpd[15682]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[::1]: 554 5.7.1 <momchilrogelov@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<ubuntu@debeldecibel.com> to=<momc$
Jun 30 18:27:46 vm21 postfix/smtpd[15682]: lost connection after RCPT from unknown[::1]
Jun 30 18:27:46 vm21 postfix/smtpd[15682]: disconnect from unknown[::1]
```

the /etc/hosts file has

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

and this is my postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 4h
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = debeldecibel.com, localhost
myhostname = smtp.debeldecibel.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "address not listed for localhost" message is misleading. Use:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this save my day. To others, the location of this file is **/etc/postfix/mail.cf** (##line number 264)

Answer (score 0):

Check the /etc/hosts file.
Is the ipv6 address for localhost inserted?
The line should be like:

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

If not add it and restart postfix.
Try to send again the email.

Comment: it is there. this is not the issue